# Summing by Match/Index with one fix and one variant criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have the following table.

```
    Column A    Column B         Column C  

1  Board Size   Quantity         Classroom      <----- (Column header)
2     240          1           Classroom - 1
3     660          4           Classroom - 1
4     1100         1           Classroom - 1
5     1100         1           Classroom - 2
6     240          4           Classroom - 2
7     660          1           Classroom - 2
8     240          1           Classroom - 3
9     660          3           Classroom - 3
10    1100         2           Classroom - 3
```

**My first request:**
In the below table, I want to say in `F2`, for example:
When `E2` matches to `Column C` AND `$F$1` matches to `Column A`, then give me the correspondence Quantity Value in `Column B`.

**My second request:**
In `G2`, instead, I want to have the sum, when `$E$2` matches to `Column C` AND `$G$1` matches to `Column A`.

```
    Column E         Column F       Column G  

1   Classroom          240            240         <----- (Column header)
2   Classroom - 1       1              6
3   Classroom - 2       4   
4   Classroom - 3       1
```

[image: Screehshot]

Can anyone help me to do that with MATCH/INDEX, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In F2:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,$F$1,C:C,$E2)
```

and Copy down

In G2:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,$G$1)
```

---

To use INDEX/MATCH it must be an array form of the formula:

In F2:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$10=$F$1)*($C$2:$C$10 = $E2),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Another draw back to  Array formulas is that one should not use full column references as the formula will calculate every cell referenced, that is over 2 million calculations for each formula.

The reference needs to be for the data set only.

The formula in G2 will remain the same as it cannot be done with an INDEX/MATCH, as INDEX/MATCH will only return the first number and not any others.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Your suggestion is very clever and easy, but I want to do it with Match/Index.

Comment: The match Index will need to be an array formula, which can lead to problems.  And one should avoid array formulas when non array formulas are available, for speed.  @dio.

Comment: @Dio and the second formula, the one in G2 cannot be done with INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: about the sum in G2, you are right, I will do it with SUMIFS. But the INDEX formula returns #NA. Have you any idea why?

Comment: I applied it as array, but doesn't the result is the same.

Comment: @dio it works for me.  sorry I can't do a screen grab at the moment.  Does your formula have the `{}` around it, put there by Excel?  Check and make sure that the data is the same, that there are no extra spaces or other unprintable characters.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I checked that, the {} are inserted by excel. I do Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: @Dio check your data.  Check to make sure that the numbers are all numbers and not text.  make sure there are no spaces or any other non printable characters that are not in the criteria.  You have a criteria and data mismatch.

Comment: @Dio see edit for proof the formula works.

Comment: you were right. Some numbers in `Column A` were saved as text. I changed them and the formula works. I deeply appreciate your help.